# How to unit test a pure ASGI middleware in python

Tags: python, fastapi, middleware, asgi

I have an ASGI middleware that adds fields to the POST request body before it hits the route in my fastapi app.

```
from starlette.types import ASGIApp, Message, Scope, Receive, Send

class MyMiddleware:
    """
    This middleware implements a raw ASGI middleware instead of a starlette.middleware.base.BaseHTTPMiddleware
    because the BaseHTTPMiddleware does not allow us to modify the request body.
    For documentation see https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#pure-asgi-middleware
    """
    def __init__(self, app: ASGIApp):
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send):
        if scope["type"] != "http":
            await self.app(scope, receive, send)
            return ""

        async def modify_message():
            message: dict = await receive()
            if message.get("type", "") != "http.request":
                return message
            if not message.get("body", None):
                return message
            body: dict = json.loads(message.get("body", b"'{}'").decode("utf-8"))
            body["some_field"] = "foobar"
            message["body"] = json.dumps(body).encode("utf-8")
            return message

        await self.app(scope, modify_message, send)
```

Is there an example on how to unit test an ASGI middleware? I would like to test directly the `__call__` part which is difficult as it does not return anything. Do I need to use a test api client (e.g. `TestClient` from fastapi) to then create some dummy endpoint which returns the request as response and thereby check if the middleware was successful or is there a more "direct" way?

Comment: One way would be to create a `TestClient`, apply the middleware, send some requests through and assert that `"some_field"` is set in the body.

Comment: @M.O. that's what I ended up doing, and I can live with that

Comment: You can look at the [Starlette's test suite](https://github.com/encode/starlette/tree/master/tests/middleware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the similar problem recently, so I want to share my solution for `fastapi` and `pytest`.

I had to implement per request logs for the fastapi app using middlewares.

I've checked [Starlette's test suite](https://github.com/encode/starlette/tree/master/tests/middleware) as [Marcelo Trylesinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13087720/marcelo-trylesinski) suggested and adapted the code to fit fastapi. Thank you for the recommendation, Marcelo!

Here is my middleware that logs information from every request and response.

```
# middlewares.py
import logging

from starlette.types import ASGIApp, Scope, Receive, Send


logger = logging.getLogger("app")


class LogRequestsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app: ASGIApp) -> None:
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(
        self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send
    ) -> None:
        async def send_with_logs(message):
            """Log every request info and response status code."""
            if message["type"] == "http.response.start":
                # request info is stored in the scope
                # status code is stored in the message
                logger.info(
                    f'{scope["client"][0]}:{scope["client"][1]} - '
                    f'"{scope["method"]} {scope["path"]} '
                    f'{scope["scheme"]}/{scope["http_version"]}" '
                    f'{message["status"]}'
                )
            await send(message)

        await self.app(scope, receive, send_with_logs)
```

To test a middleware, I had to create test_factory_client fixture:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


@pytest.fixture
def test_client_factory() -> TestClient:
    return TestClient
```

In the test, I mocked `logger.info()` call within the middleware and asserted if the method was called.

```
# test_middlewares.py
from unittest import mock
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import FastAPI
from .middlewares import LogRequestsMiddleware

# mock logger call within the pure middleware
@mock.patch("path.to.middlewares.logger.info")
def test_log_requests_middleware(
    mock_logger, test_client_factory: TestClient
):
    # create a fresh app instance to isolate tested middlewares
    app = FastAPI()
    app.add_middleware(LogRequestsMiddleware)
    
    # create an endpoint to test middlewares
    @app.get("/")
    def homepage():
        return {"hello": "world"}

    # create a client for the app using fixure
    client = test_client_factory(app)

    # call an endpoint
    response = client.get("/")

    # sanity check
    assert response.status_code == 200
    # check if the logger was called
    mock_logger.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: can we log the request body and response body?